# How to retain multiple checkbox even page refreshes reset after form submit

Tags: php, jquery

i have a form of multiple checkboxes. but i want to retain the checkbox checked but reset it after form submit. here is my code.

```
<?php

if(isset($_POST['query'])){
$searched = $_POST['query'];
$conn = mysqli_connect('localhost','root','','orderqueing') or die (mysqli_error());
$query = "SELECT * FROM product_tbl WHERE itemName LIKE '%$searched%'";
$result = mysqli_query($conn, $query);
while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)){
     echo '<label style="float:left" class="option_item">
  <input type="checkbox" id="mycheckbox" class="checkbox" name="prodid[]" value="'.$row['itemName'].'">
  <div class="option_inner facebook">
    <div class="tickmark"></div>
    <div class="icon">'.$row['itemName'].'<input type="hidden" name="prodname[]" value="'.$row['itemName'].'"></div>
    <div class="icon">'.$row['itemPrice'].' PHP<input type="hidden" name="price[]" value="'.$row['itemPrice'].'"></div>
    <div class="icon"><input type="number" name="multiple[]" style="padding:5px;width:60px;" value="1" ></div>
 </div>
</label>';
}

}   else {
    
    $conn = mysqli_connect('localhost','root','','orderqueing') or die (mysqli_error());
    $query = "SELECT * FROM product_tbl";
    $result = mysqli_query($conn, $query);
    while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)){
    echo '<label style="float:left" class="option_item">
    <input type="checkbox" id="mycheckbox" class="checkbox" name="prodid[]" value="'.$row['itemName'].'">
    <div class="option_inner facebook">
    <div class="tickmark"></div>
    <div class="icon">'.$row['itemName'].'<input type="hidden" name="prodname[]" value="'.$row['itemName'].'"></div>
    <div class="icon">'.$row['itemPrice'].' PHP<input type="hidden" name="price[]" value="'.$row['itemPrice'].'"></div>
    <div class="icon"><input type="number" name="multiple[]" style="padding:5px;width:60px;" value="1" ></div>
    </div>
    </label>';
    }
}
```

?>

this is my UI :
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mLGcY.png)

because the checked checkboxes resets when i search an item.
i want to retain it checked before the form submits.
i could not think of a solution to this problem. thanks for the help

Comment: What have you tried to resolve the problem? Where are you stuck? Why is this tagged with jQuery, but does not contain any JS code?

Comment: Also, be warned that your `SELECT` query is highly vulnerable for SQL injection. Have a look at prepared statements to avoid getting hacked

Comment: hi, i just want to retain a checkbox to be checked before the user gets to submit the form. but the problem is. i have a jquery keyup. function. that when i searched an item the checked. checkboxes became unchecked.

Comment: Please add all clarification to your question by editing it. Also, why not gather the checkboxes' state before replacing the markup, and restore that state afterwards?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can consider recording the checkbox you selected in the cookie when submitting or at the end of the keyup function; then get the cookie in window.onload or your code and give the corresponding checkbox a selected state

I'm not quite sure if you are requesting this data via ajax.This is untested code, but provides an idea; you may need to modify or even use
I thought of the following workaround:

```js
window.onload=function(){
  //Called after initialization or search. Check the checkbox
  function reloadCheckBox(){
    let allProdCheck =          document.querySelectorAll("input[name=prodid[]]");
    allProdCheck.forEach(element => {
      let cooki = getCookie("prod_"+element.value);
      if(cooki!=''&&Boolean(cooki)==true){ //if exists (previously selected)
        element.checked = true;
      }else{
        element.checked = false;
      }
    });
  }
}
  //Record in cookie when selected
  function prodCheck(ele){
    setCookie("prod_"+ele.value,ele.checked);
  }

  function setCookie(cname,cvalue='',exdays=1){
      var d = new Date();
      //d.setTime(d.getTime()+(exdays*24*60*60*1000));
      //var expires = "expires="+d.toGMTString();
      //document.cookie = cname+"="+cvalue+"; "+expires;
      document.cookie = cname+"="+cvalue;
  }
  function getCookie(cname){
      var name = cname + "=";
      var ca = document.cookie.split(';');
      for(var i=0; i<ca.length; i++) {
          var c = ca[i].trim();
          if (c.indexOf(name)==0) { return c.substring(name.length,c.length); }
      }
      return "";
  }
```

Then add event `onclick="prodCheck(this)"` to this statement `<input type="checkbox" id="mycheckbox" class="checkbox" name="prodid[]" value="'.$row[' itemName'].'" >`

```
<input type="checkbox" id="mycheckbox" class="checkbox" name="prodid[]" value="'.$row['itemName'].'" onclick="prodCheck(this)" >
```

---

you saied cant figure it out on how to use it in multiple checkboxes?http://jsfiddle.net/Lwxoeyyp/1/

```
<input type="button" id="ReserveerButton1" value="save" onclick="save()"/>
<input type="button" id="Wisbutton1" value="delete" onclick="wis()"/>
<input type="checkbox" id="checkbox1zaal1" onchange="checkChange(this)">1e film van de dag</input>
<input type="checkbox" id="checkbox1zaal2" onchange="checkChange(this)">1e film van de dag</input>
<input type="checkbox" id="checkbox1zaal3" onchange="checkChange(this)">1e film van de dag</input>
```

```
function load(){
    let checks = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('checkbox'));
    if(checks!={}){
        for(let key in checks){
　　　　document.getElementById(key).checked = checks[key];
　　  }
    }
}

/*one checkbox is checked or unchecked
If you want to use the save method you wrote, you can pass the corresponding single checkbox object as the parameter
*/
function checkChange(ele){
    let oldCheck = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('checkbox'));
  if(oldCheck==null||oldCheck=={}){
    oldCheck={};
  }
  oldCheck[ele.id] = ele.checked;
    localStorage.setItem('checkbox', JSON.stringify(oldCheck));
}

load();
```

Comment: thankyou, but can i ask for a sample on how to do it?

Comment: Are you trying to achieve that the selected item will still show up when the search doesn't match?

Comment: yes and even the search matches. and when i select the item first before i searched i want to still be checked even after i searched.

Comment: thanks for the code sir, but it doesn't work. my selected checkboxes still resets to uncheck when i refresh the page.

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/Lwxoeyyp/1/ like this one sir, but on multiple checkboxes with multiple data. my checkboxes holds a data from the database using while loop or fetch_array. the sample is applicable only in one checkbox. but i cant figure it out on how to use it in multiple checkboxes. please refer to this link: http://jsfiddle.net/Lwxoeyyp/1/

Comment: thank you sir!, it works. even i searched and the php file load in terms of the condition. but the checkbox remain checked. i just cant figure out how an array would work with document.getElementById. this is great. thanks a lot! this would be my reference for my future projects.